# Dynamic Properties for object instances?

Tags: object, dynamic, model, properties

After the previous question "What are the important rules in Object Model Design", now I want to ask this:

**Is there any way to have dynamic properties for class instances?**

Suppose that we have this schematic object model:

[image: object model]

So, each object could have lots of properties due to the set of implemented Interfaces, and then become relatively heavy object. Creating all the possible -and of course reasonable- object can be a way for solving this problem *(i.e. Pipe_Designed v.s. Pipe_Designed_NeedInspection)*, but I have a large number of interfaces by now, that make it difficult.
I wonder if there is a way to have dynamic properties, something like the following dialog to allow the end user to select available functionalities for his/hers new object.

[image: dialog]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is `Properties pattern`. Check out long and boring but clever article from [Steve Yegge on this](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/10/universal-design-pattern.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the number of public properties, use explicit interface implementation.

If you mean fields (and object space for sparse objects): you can always use a property bag for the property implementation.

For a C# example:

```
string IDesigned.ApprovedBy {
    get {return GetValue<string>("ApprovedBy");}
    set {SetValue("ApprovedBy", value);}
}
```

with a dictionary for the values:

```
readonly Dictionary<string, object> propValues =
    new Dictionary<string, object>();
protected T GetValue<T>(string name)
{
    object val;
    if(!propValues.TryGetValue(name, out val)) return default(T);
    return (T)val;
}
protected void SetValue<T>(string name, T value)
{
    propValues[name] = value;
}
```

Note that `SetValue` would also be a good place for any notifications - for example, `INotifyPropertyChanged` in .NET to implement the observer pattern. Many other architectures have something similar. You can do the same with object keys (like how `EventHandlerList` works), but string keys are simpler to understand ;-p

This only then takes as much space as the properties that are actively being used.

A final option is to encapsulate the various facets;

```
class Foo {
    public bool IsDesigned {get {return Design != null;}}
    public IDesigned Design {get;set;}
    // etc
}
```

Here `Foo` doesn't implement any of the interfaces, but provides access to them as properties.

Comment: Dear Marc
Your answer is very helpfull and specially complete, I choose steve article as the best answer, because it gave me more detail.
Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you're putting too many roles into the "Road" and "Pipe" classes, because your need for dynamic properties seems to derive from various states/phases of the artifacts in your model. I would consider making an explicit model using associations to different classes instead of putting everything in the "Road" or "Pipe" class using interfaces.